# Editing Dynamic Distribution Group Filter to exclude Users

Tags: filter, office365, exchange-server

I need help in modifying a dynamic distribution group filter to exclude two users (by using aliases).

**Current Filter:**

```
-RecipientFilter ((((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -or
 (((((RecipientType -eq 'MailUser') -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetails -eq
 'RoomMailbox')))) -and (Company -like 'ABC Papers*'))))) -and
 (-not(Name -like 'SystemMailbox{*')) -and (-not(Name -like 'CAS_{*'))
 -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'MailboxPlan')) -and
 (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'DiscoveryMailbox')) -and
 (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'PublicFolderMailbox')) -and 
(-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'ArbitrationMailbox')) -and 
(-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'AuditLogMailbox')) -and 
(-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'AuxAuditLogMailbox')) -and
 (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'SupervisoryReviewPolicyMailbox')))
```

**Need to add exclusion like:**

```
 -and (Alias -ne ‘user1’)) -and (Alias -Ne ‘user2’))
```

Also, any best practices to modify filters if there are multiple exclusions? Using attributes to exclude is a better way but if not then understanding the logic behind this filter would help. So I would appreciate any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell Command

```
Set-DynamicDistributionGroup -Identity "DDG Name Here" -RecipientFilter {((RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'UserMailbox' -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'MailUser') -and (Alias -ne 'user1' -or Alias -ne 'user2') -and (Company -like 'ABC Papers*'))}
```

### RecipientFilter Breakdown

**First group** - satisfies the requirement for a user mailbox or mailuser, but not a room mailbox.  Note that I used RecipientTypeDetails instead of RecipientType, which the latter will include shared mailboxes.

```
(RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'UserMailbox' -or RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'MailUser')
```

**Second group** - satisfies your `Alias` filter requirements.  Note that it isn't recommended to include too many single object filters, as this defeats the dynamically generated aspect of these groups and you start to turn it into a regular distribution group.

```
(Alias -ne 'user1' -or Alias -ne 'user2')
```

**Third group** - satisfies your `Company` filter requirement.

```
(Company -like 'ABC Papers*')
```

All three groups are then grouped together.  With OPath, you can group same attributes to achieve the desired effect.  You also do not need to include all the system generated filters starting with the `-and(-not(Name -like 'SystemMailbox{*'))` as these are automatically added.

[List of filterable properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/recipientfilter-properties?view=exchange-ps)

[RecipientFilter MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/recipient-filters?view=exchange-ps#additional-opath-syntax-information)